# JS function calling after declaring it

Tags: javascript

I was asked to write some code to make the placeholder for an input to disappear when `onfocus` and turn back again when `onblur`.

It was working when I wrote the code this way:

```js
myInput.onfocus = function () { code here } -- myInput.onblur = function () { code here }.
```

But when I tried to define the two function first, then call them, it doesn't work.

Like this:

```js
function clrplaceholder(x) {
    "use strict";
    // storing the value of the placeholder
    x.setAttribute("bkplaceholder", x.getAttribute("placeholder"));

    // removing the value of the placeholder
    x.setAttribute("placeholder", "");
}

function addplaceholder(y) {
    "use strict";
    // get the value of the placeholder from our backup
    y.setAttribute("placeholder", y.getAttribute("bkplaceholder"));

    // removing the value of the backupplaceholder
    y.setAttribute("bkplaceholder", "");
}

our2Input.onfocus = clrplaceholder(our2Input);
our2Input.onblur = addplaceholder(our2Input);
```

Why does the first way work and the second doesn't?

Comment: Why must use javascript? Just `<input type="text" placeholder="foo" />`

Comment: Agree with @Tân. The HTML input's placeholder attribute does exactly, what you're trying to achieve without any additional javascript.

Comment: @Tân .. No it isn't working .. I think u have misunderstand something.. I mean that when the input is infocus state the placeholder disappear . . not when you begin to write as the browser do as default..

Comment: Got your point @MohammedKhaled! Thanks for the comment!

Comment: Here is the demonstration of the difference between the default placeholder behavior and, what @MohammedKhaled needs to achieve: https://jsfiddle.net/skorav/q1s2yev6/

Comment: that is right @AndriiS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the addEventListener method of the event targets:

```
our2Input.addEventListener('focus', clrplaceholder);
our2Input.addEventListener('blur', addplaceholder);
```

And you need to modify your event handlers to actually work with the event targets:

```
function clrplaceholder(event) {
    "use strict";
    const x = event.currentTarget;
    // storing the value of the placeholder
    x.setAttribute("bkplaceholder", x.getAttribute("placeholder"));

    // removing the value of the placeholder
    x.setAttribute("placeholder", "");
}

function addplaceholder(event) {
    "use strict";
    const y = event.currentTarget;
    // get the value of the placeholder from our backup
    y.setAttribute("placeholder", y.getAttribute("bkplaceholder"));

    // removing the value of the backupplaceholder
    y.setAttribute("bkplaceholder", "");
}
```

Comment: thaks for your right answer it actually working good, but do you mean that the best way to do it is by using addEventListener?? ..

Comment: Yes, binding an event is actually done like this. And it has its advantages described in the respective MDN article: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Why_use_addEventListener

Answer (score 1):

Here you are calling / executing the function you have defined. These two functions returns undefined (default return value for a function when no return statement is used inside)

So basically it's like doing this :

```
input.onfocus = undefined
```

And this will not work. What you want to do is actually passing a reference to your function so that later when the input will blur it will call your function.
You pass a function reference by just giving its name (no parenthesis, you execute / call it when you use parenthesis)

```
input.onfocus = myFunctionName
```

This is the answer for your problem BUT you actually don't have to do that with javascript since it's the default behavior on the brower (when you type the placeholder disappear)

Just use the attribute placeholder onto the input html tag like so :

```
<input type='text' placeholder="my placeholder text" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use fat arrow function.

```js
our2Input.onfocus = { ()=> clrplaceholder(our2Input) }
our2Input.onblur = { ()=>addplaceholder(our2Input) }
```

Comment: Why fat arrow function and not a regular anonymous function? And most importantly why is it required to use one of those? An answer without an explanation is not really helpful.